# What does it take to get FaceBook to stop pushing notifications to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, notifications, facebook

I don't want FaceBook to put any notifications on my iPhone's home screen for anything, ever.

I've gone into the iPhone's "settings" app and turned off **all**  notifications for FaceBook.

I've gone into the settings within the FB app itself and turned off all push notifications.

But I **still** get notifications.

What more do they want from me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is something FaceBook is good at, it's in bothering it's users :)
So make sure you've unchecked those items:

Make sure you've switched the **Notification Center**-slider to off and the **Alert Style** to none in such a way FaceBook is listed in the **Not In Notification Center**.

[image]
[image]

And if you go to **Settings < FaceBook**, make sure you're **Push Notifications** are all switched off.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did it turn off your push notifications?

Comment: So far, yes. It appears to have done so.

Answer (score 1):

> Settings -> Notifications

You have to choose **none** in the notification style menu, and **disable all buttons**.

Answer (score -1):

Go onto the persons page that u want to block you notifications from then click "friends"/"add frien" and press notifications and when u press it,it will get rid of a tick on the right hand side! If in stead a tick appears. press it again to stop the notifications! hope this answer helped! thanks! :)

Comment: But OP wants iOS notifications turned off not FB notifications. And please use grammatical English in the answer so that it may be understood.